# Moving 3d object in Webgl with keyboard arrow keys

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, webgl2

I just finished an assignment to create a rotating pyramid but I want to take this a bit further and see how I can move this object within the canvas using the keyboard arrow keys. I will post my full code below and the main piece of code starts on line 143 where I have document.addEventListener and then doing a switch (key) - I believe (in researching) this should work but what I don't understand is why it's not updating dynamically - like, each time I push left arrow key it should move left. I am using the gl.viewport (x,y,canvas.width, canvas.height) and trying to update the (x,y) pieces of the viewport because if I manually enter in x or y the object will move so I think this is the piece of the project I need to update to move the object, I believe... here is my code, any tips would be great. My shaders are in the html file but don't think that is needed but if so, let me know and I can post that as well. Just looking for tips on how to move the object so I can apply that technique going forward. Thanks in advance.

```
    "use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;

var numPositions  = 12;

var texSize = 1024;
var numChecks = 32;

var program;

var texture1, texture2, texture3, texture4;
var t1, t2;

var c;

var flag = true;

var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "coolWater.jpg";
image1.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "coolWater.jpg";
image2.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = "coolWater.jpg";
image3.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

var image4 = new Image();
image4.src = "coolWater.jpg";
image4.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

var positionsArray = [];
var colorsArray = [];
var texCoordsArray = [];

var texCoord = [
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 0)
];


var vertices = [
    vec4(0.5, -0.2722,  0.2866, 1.0),
    vec4(0.0, -0.2722,  -0.5773, 1.0),
    vec4(-0.5, -0.2722,  0.2886, 1.0),
    vec4(0.0, 0.5443,  0.0, 1.0)
];

//changing colors to white so you can just see the texture applied
var vertexColors = [
    vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
    vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
    vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
    vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
];

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;
var axis = xAxis;

var theta = vec3(45.0, 45.0, 45.0);

var thetaLoc;

function configureTexture() {
    texture1 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image1);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                      gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    
    
    texture2 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image2);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                      gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    texture3 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture3);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image3);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                      gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    
    
    texture4 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture4);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image4);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                      gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    
}

function tri(a, b, c) {
     positionsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[a]);

     positionsArray.push(vertices[b]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[b]);

     positionsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[c]);
}

function colorPyramid()
{
    tri(2, 1, 3);
    tri(3, 1, 0);
    tri(0, 1, 2);
    tri(0, 2, 3);
}


window.onload = function init() {
    
    canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");

    gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
    if (!gl) alert("WebGL 2.0 isn't available");

    //creating if / else statements for arrow keys pressed
    var xPos = 0;
    var yPos = 0;

    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const key = e.key; // This will hold the arrow keys pressed
        switch (key) {
          case "ArrowLeft":
            // Left Arrow pressed move object to the left
            xPos += -25;
            break;
          case "ArrowRight":
            // Right Arrow pressed move object to the right
            xPos += 25;
            break;
          case "ArrowUp":
            // Up Arrow pressed move object up
            yPos += 25;
            break;
          case "ArrowDown":
            // Down Arrow pressed move object down
            yPos += -25;
            break;
        }
      });

    gl.viewport(xPos, yPos, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    gl.useProgram(program);

    colorPyramid();

    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var colorLoc = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "aColor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLoc, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLoc);

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(positionsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "aPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc );

    var tBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(texCoordsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var texCoordLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aTexCoord");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLoc);




    configureTexture();

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation( program, "uTex0"), 0);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1 );
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation( program, "uTex1"), 1);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE2 );
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture3);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation( program, "uTex1"), 2);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE3 );
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture4);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation( program, "uTex1"), 3);

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uTheta");


 document.getElementById("ButtonX").onclick = function(){axis = xAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonY").onclick = function(){axis = yAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonZ").onclick = function(){axis = zAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonT").onclick = function(){flag = !flag;};

    render();
}

var render = function() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    if(flag) theta[axis] += 2.0;
    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numPositions);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on your desire to expand your knowledge and to "take this a bit further". I'll try to help answer your question.

From reading your question, it appears that you believe passing an `(x, y)` location to `gl.viewport` will move your pyramid to location `(x, y)` on the screen. Changing the `(x, y)` value may appear to move your rendered shape, but really it's a coincidence of resizing the render viewport. It's similar to resizing your browser window and having various page elements be shrunk down to fit the new window size.

In your example, you passed an angle into your WebGL program to make the pyramid rotate:

```
thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uTheta");
...
if(flag) theta[axis] += 2.0;
gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);
```

In order to move the element on the screen, you need to take a similar approach of creating a `uX` and `uY` uniform variables, updating them and re-rendering whenever you press the arrow keys.

```
xLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uX");
yLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uX");
...
gl.uniform1fv(xLoc, xPos);
gl.uniform1fv(xLoc, yPos);

Without seeing your complete code, including shaders, I won't be able to put together a working example.
```